# BusinessObjects (BoE) / Crystal Server: old/dead sessions not being cleared

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects

We have a BusinessObjects Enterprise XI server which I believe is similar (if not the same) to Crystal Reports Server 2008.

We have a small number of concurrent licenses, and is has never been a problem before (that we've noticed), but lately it seems that the server isn't getting rid of dead sessions, and is counting them as active still (which is counting against our licensing).

We did not use the Tomcat server for the web presence, so this may be affecting it as well (we are using the web server that comes internally with the server -- not sure what it is. Can you tell I inherited this project?)

The only solution I've been able to utilize so far is restarting the BoE servers (they are a number of separate applications but I can't find which manages sessions and so all must be restarted. Gross.

Any idea on where I could start to dig into this? I've searched through all manner of documentation but have yet to find the solution.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The license is released when the EnterpriseSession is terminated.  However, the EnterpriseSession isn't terminated when the browser is closed; the user needs to explicitly 'logoff' (in ePortfolio/InfoView) to end the session.

You could also shorten length of the default session.

From the BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 3.1 Administrator's Guide (page 444-445):

> Enterprise systems dedicated to serving a large number of users
>   typically require some form of distributed security. An enterprise
>   system may require distributed security to support features such the
>   transfer of trust (the ability to allow another component to act on
>   behalf of the user) BusinessObjects Enterprise addresses distributed
>   security by implementing a ticket mechanism (one that is similar to
>   the Kerberos ticket mechanism). The CMS grants tickets that authorize
>   components to perform actions on behalf of a particular user. In
>   BusinessObjects Enterprise, the ticket is referred to as the logon
>   token.
>
> This logon token is most commonly used over the Web. When a user is
>   first authenticated by BusinessObjects Enterprise, he or she receives
>   a logon token from the CMS. The user's web browser caches this logon
>   token. When the user makes a new request, other BusinessObjects
>   Enterprise components can read the logon token from the user's web
>   browser.
>
> In general, a session is a client-server connection that enables the
>   exchange of information between the two computers. A session's state
>   is a set of data that describes the session's attributes, its
>   configuration, or its content. When you establish a client-server
>   connection over the Web, the nature of HTTP limits the duration of
>   each session to a single page of information; thus, your web browser
>   retains the state of each session in memory only for as long as any
>   single Web page is displayed. As soon as you move from one web page to
>   another, the state of the first session is discarded and replaced with
>   the state of the next session. Consequently, Web sites and Web
>   applications must somehow store the state of one session if they need
>   to reuse its information in another.
>
> BusinessObjects Enterprise uses two common methods to store session
>   state:
>
> • Cookies—A cookie is a small text file that stores session
>   state on the client side: the user's web browser caches the cookie for
>   later use. The BusinessObjects Enterprise logon token is an example of
>   this method.
>
> • Session variables—A session variable is a portion of memory that
>   stores session state on the server side. When BusinessObjects
>   Enterprise grants a user an active identity on the system, information
>   such as the user's authentication type is stored in a session
>   variable. So long as the session is maintained, the system neither has
>   to prompt the user for the information a second time nor has to repeat
>   any task that is necessary for the completion of the next request. For
>   Java deployments, the session is used to handle .jsp requests; for
>   .NET deployments, the session is used to handle .aspx requests.
>
> Note:
>
> Ideally, the system should preserve the session variable while the
>   user is active on the system. And, to ensure security and to minimize
>   resource usage, the system should destroy the session variable as soon
>   as the user has finished working on the system. However, because the
>   interaction between a web browser and a web server can be stateless,
>   it can be difficult to know when users leave the system, if they do
>   not log off explicitly. To address this issue, BusinessObjects
>   Enterprise implements session tracking.
>
> The CMS implements a simple tracking algorithm. When a user logs on,
>   the user is granted a CMS session, which the CMS preserves until the
>   user logs off, or until the web application server session variable is
>   released.
>
> The web application server session is designed to notify the CMS on a
>   recurring basis that it is still active, so the CMS session is
>   retained so long as the web application server session exists. If the
>   web application server session fails to communicate with the CMS for a
>   ten-minute time period, the CMS destroys the CMS session. This handles
>   scenarios where client-side components shut down irregularly.

Comment: Question regarding: "The CMS implements a simple tracking algorithm. When a user logs on, the user is granted a CMS session, which the CMS preserves until the user logs off, or until the web application server session variable is released." When they say web application server session is released, they are referring to Tomcat I'm assuming, but we are not using Tomcat. What is the best way to update this session timeout for non-Tomcat installs? Thanks for the great excerpt from the Admin guide!

Comment: Another follow-up question: I see that "If the web application server session fails to communicate with the CMS for a ten-minute time period, the CMS destroys the CMS session." we are using the internal web server, and I've noted sessions left for days in Crystal (where users have no browser windows open anymore and the last login is days ago). Where is this 10-minute rule implemented if not using the Tomcat installation?

Comment: 1) Either Tomcat or IIS (depends on which version you installed).  2) How do you know that the open sessions are related to these particular browsers?  Have you determined what your default, Enterprise timeout settings are?  If you create a session with a browser, then let it sit (don't close it) for a period of inactivity that should cause re-authentication, what happens?  Are you using SSO?

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue where the admin was always counted twice from our small no of named licences our provider complained to SAP on our behalf and they gave us a free named licences as they couldn't resolve it. Maybe your provider could get SAP to remote on and take a look for you.

The concurrent licences when users fail to log out are cleared by restarting the central configuration manager, that's how SAP showed me and yes it is a full restart.

If you have any live reports open in development via crystal reports you will lose connection to your database so you may want to close or save them before restarting.

The servers will eventually comeback up and your open sessions will be cleared down fully